# Use offline package without downloading them with MapLoader

Tags: android, here-api

We're deploying our application that uses the here sdk for navigation and we would like to copy the offline maps on the device when we install our application. Problem is that I can't find a way to install the offline maps without using the MapLoader.

Is there a way to install the offline maps without having to download them directly from the server (the France package weights 1,3Gb and we have 200 devices...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please contact HERE technical support. This is not something we generally offer to all customers.